# Flutter Image.memory loading shows nothing

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Basically, I am trying to make an animation by transforming a grayscale image into a full-color image. 
The full-color image is loaded in this way:

```
    ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load("...");
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return (await fi.image.toByteData()).buffer.asUint8List();
```

In the animation widget, what I did is simply change part of image data into greyscale and keep the rest the same. This issue is that when I convert the bytes into image widget in this way:

```
    return Image.memory(
      imglib.encodePng(imglib.Image.fromBytes(
          widget.rawWidth, widget.rawHeight, p)));
```

p is the modified version of the bytes in original picture. 
However, on the screen, nothing appears. And calling

```
    return Image.memory(p);
```

will trigger exception on instantiateCodec failed due to lack of metadata. 
Any ideas about how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figure a way to get away from it. For this issue above, I guess it is caused by slow image operation and displaying under 60 frames/s rate. What I did instead to build a stack with front image clip by animation value.